# reversing a string two char by two char

Tags: java, string, reverse

I'm trying to develop a program that convert 6 bytes into a hexadecimal representation (like 00:65:36:21:A5:BC)

with this method :

```
public static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(18);
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            if (sb.length() > 0)
                sb.append(':');
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }
```

I'm obtaining a good format, but now I have to reverse the digits two by two.

what I obtain 00:65:36:21:A5:BC

what I should get BC:A5:21:36:65:00

Can anybody help me on that final step ?? I'm struggling to take each pair of digits and reverse its position (putting BC at the beginning, but without changing its order (like CB)

Thanks in advance

G.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to reverse `bytes`? Or even to iterate `bytes` in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a reverse regular `for` instead of a `for each`

```
public static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(18);
    for (int i = bytes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (sb.length() > 0)
            sb.append(':');
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", bytes[i]));
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```

Comment: oooh!! didnt think of that....gosh i should have^^ thanks anyway, works fine!!! (thanks everybody by the way!!)

Answer (score 4):

To append at the beginning rather than appending to the last, use this:

```
sb.insert(0, text);
```

instead of this:

```
sb.append(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the insert method of the StringBuilder class instead of the append method, with an offset of 0.

You can read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html).